# Java checkstyle - constructor definition in wrong order

Tags: java, checkstyle

I have a class that looks like this:

```
public final class OrderedSetList<T extends Comparable<? super T>> implements OrderedSet<T> {

    // Constructor definition in wrong order checkstyle error next line
    public OrderedSetList() {      
        // Initializations
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me why there is a **"Constructor definition in wrong order"** error in my constructor?

It's an assignment and we have our own checkstyle configs and any checkstyle error is not allowed.

I appreciated your help.

Comment: Is the constructor the first method?

Comment: @Glitch Nope. Is this a problem?

Comment: I think that checkstyle rule wants the constructor as the first method. Try shifting it up to just below your variables.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The [checkstyle rule](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_coding.html#DeclarationOrder) is making sure you are following the code conventions for the order of your declarations:

> The parts of a class or interface declaration should appear in the following order: 
>    **Class (static) variables**. First the public class variables, then the protected, then package level (no access modifier), and then the private. 
>    **Instance variables**. First the public class variables, then the protected, then package level (no access modifier), and then the private.  
>    **Constructors**  
>    **Methods**

It wants the constructor to be the first method.

Comment: You should also quote the checkstyle rules, a few points are not that much to copy.